# Interpreting what it means when the units, $\frac{\text{success rate}}{\text{time}}\cdot \text{currency}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, dimensional-analysis

**You are applying for a \$1000 scholarship and your time is worth \$10 an hour. If the chance of success is $1 -(1/x)$ from $x$ hours of writing, when should you stop?**

My way if thinking eventually led to the correct answer which is $\frac{1}{x^2}1000=10$. Solving for $x$ gives you the solution.

I was stuck at this problem and didn't know how to proceed and I tried to find out if I could find the answer just by matching up the units on both sides. Let $p(x)$ be the rate of success as a function of time, $x$. I don't know how they calculated $p(x)$ but I do know that it is dimensionless. Thus, $p'(x)$ will give me the rate of sucess per unit time or just the unit, $1/h$. I know that \$1000 has dollar units and that $10\frac{$}{h}$ has dollar per hour unit, so if I multiply $p'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ with \$1000 I should get the same units as $10\frac{$}{h}$. So I set $\frac{1}{x^2}1000=10$ and solved for $x$. Feeling doubtful, I checked the solution and was surprised how I got it right.

My question is how do you interpret the solution, $\frac{1}{x^2}1000=10$? Like since $p'(x)$ is defined as the success rate per unit time, how come if I multiplied it by \$1000, it got me the solution? I just don't understand it, $$\frac{\text{success rate}}{\text{time}}\cdot \text{currency}$$

How do you interpret this? and yes, I'm aware that the success rate is dimensionless but still, I don't understand the reasoning behind the answer. I just want someone to solve the problem with also providing some commentary on his/her methods of solving it.

Comment: This question is very confusingly phrased (espesially the title). Why are you asking about units? Isn't your problem that you don't know how to solve the problem (you solved it by matching up units) instead of understanding the basics here?

Comment: Write up what you expect to gain as function of time $W(x)$. Then write down how much it costs you as function of time $C(x)$. Then the expected value is given by $E(x) = W(x) - C(x)$. You want to maximixe this which leads to considering $E'(x) = 0$ (and this leads to $1000/x^2 = 10$).

Comment: @Winther Yes, that is the problem, My reasoning was not good and I want to know the correct way to think about this problem.